# HTML Table appears distorted in Outlook Email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I've created an email template and this email gets sent to outlook 2010 from my application(Oracle UCM).Issue is my workflow history table (code below) gets distorted and moves to left when checked on any mobile device However the entire email looks good when seen on a desktop.

```
    <table border="1"cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="95%" align="center">
    <tr>
       <td align="center" colspan="2" style='width:10.0%; background:#A5CEF7'>
      <p><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:red'>DMS</span><span style='font-size:15.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:red'> - <$xSubDocType$> document for <$xClientName$> PID: <$xProject_ID$> is in your workflow &nbsp;</span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td align="left" colspan="2" style='width:10.0%;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";background:#A5CEF7;font-size:12.0pt'>
      <p>
       <b>
       Click on <a href="mailto:abx@xyz.com?subject=<$regexReplaceAll(xClientName,"&","")$> <$xSubDocType$> | PID: <$xProject_ID$> | DID:<$dID$> | Approve&body=%0D%0A">Approve</a> or 
        <a href="mailto:abx@xyz.com?subject=<$regexReplaceAll(xClientName,"&","")$> <$xSubDocType$> | PID: <$xProject_ID$> | DID:<$dID$> | Reject&body= Note:%0D%0A -Enter rejection reasons(Remove this Note):">Reject</a> to take action on this document through email.Please remove your signatures(if any)</b><br><br> 
      </span>
        <span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";color:red;align="center"'>** Please note: Do not make any changes</span>  
      </p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td rowspan="2" width="40%";height="1000" style='background:#E6E6D8;min-width:200px'>                    
        <p style="padding-left:10px">
                    <span style='font-size:12pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;color:black;font-weight:bold;left:500px'>
                                    <b><u>Content Info</u>&nbsp;</b></span><br>
                                    <br>
                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">
                                    <b>Content ID:&nbsp;</b></span>
                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal">
                                    <$dDocName$></span><br>

                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">
                                    <b>Document Owner:&nbsp;</b></span>
                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal">
                                   <$UserFullName$></span><br>

                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">
                                    <b>Client:&nbsp;</b></span>
                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal">
                                    <$xClientName$></span><br>
                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">
                                    <b>Project Name&nbsp;</b></span>
                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal">
                                    <$xProjectName$></span><br>
    </p>

    <p style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;padding-left:15px">
    <$if IsNotifyOnly or wfAction like "APPROVE"$>
                    [ <a href="<$HttpCgiPath$>?IdcService=DOC_INFO&idcToken=<$idcToken$>&dID=<$dID$>&dDocName=<$url(dDocName)$>&Auth=Intranet" style="color:993333;width:300px;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-weight:normal">
                                    <$lc("wwDocumentInfo")$></a> ]</p>
    <$else$>
                    [ <a href="<$HttpCgiPath$>?IdcService=REVIEW_WORKFLOW_DOC&idcToken=<$idcToken$>&dDocName=<$url(dDocName)$>&Auth=Intranet" style="color:993333;width:300px;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-weight:normal">
                                    <$lc("wwWfReviewWorkflowItem")$></a> ]</p>

    <$endif$>            
    </td>                       
    </tr>

    <tr>        
     <td align ="center" vertical-align="top" width="60%" style='background:#E6E6D8;min-width:600px'>    
     <p style="padding-left:10px">       
    <!--    <td align ="center" vertical-align="top" width="60%" bgcolor="#E6E6D8">        -->
        <div style="display:none">  
        <$executeService("GET_SENDTOWORKFLOW_HISTORY_EMAIL_DETAILS")$>
             <$numrowSTOWFH = rsNumRows("SendtoWorkflowActionHistory")$>
            <$executeService("GET_WORKFLOW_HISTORY_EMAIL_DETAILS")$>
             <$numrowWFH = rsNumRows("WorkflowActionHistory")$>      
             <$if numrowWFH gt 0$>                   
                    <$rsRename("WorkflowActionHistory", "rsNewName")$>
             <$else$>                    
                    <$rsRename("SendtoWorkflowActionHistory", "rsNewName")$>
            <$endif$>   

        </div>  

                <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:12pt">
                    <b>Reason:&nbsp;</b></span>
                <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:12pt;color:blue">
                    <b><$if xPurposeForSubmission$><$getFieldViewValue("xPurposeForSubmission",xPurposeForSubmission,"Reason")$><$endif$></span></b><br><br>            

        <table style="position:absolute;width:97.0%;left:145px" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" id="Table2">   
                    <tr>                
                    <td style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:12pt" colspan="7">
                                <b>Recent workflow history (Maximum Last 5)</b>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>  

                    <td style="background-color:#A5CEF7;border:1px #000000 solid;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:130px;height:2px;"><div><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold"><b>Action Date</b></span></div>
                    </td>

                    <td style="background-color:#A5CEF7;border:1px #000000 solid;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:140px;height:2px;"><div><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold"><b>Action By </b></span></div>
                    </td> 

                    <td style="background-color:#A5CEF7;border:1px #000000 solid;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:70px;height:2px;"><div><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold"><b>Action </b></span></div>
                    </td>

                    <td style="background-color:#A5CEF7;border:1px #000000 solid;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:150px;height:2px;"><div><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold"><b>Action Type </b></span></div>
                    </td>

                    <td style="background-color:#A5CEF7;border:1px #000000 solid;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:250;height:2px;"><div><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold"><b>Comments</b></span></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>      
            <$loop rsNewName$>
                <tr>        
    <!-- ACTION DATE cell -->

                    <td class="<$rowClass$>" style="background-color:transparent;border:1px #000000 solid;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:130px;height:1px;">
                    <div class="xuiListCellDivCenter" nowrap><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal">
                    <$dActionDate$>&nbsp;</span></div>
                    </td>

    <!--Send To cell -->

                    <td class="<$rowClass$>" style="background-color:transparent;border:1px #000000 solid;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:100px;height:1px;">
                    <div class="xuiListCellDivCenter" nowrap>
                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal">
                    <$if strLength(getValueForSpecifiedUser(xWF_SendTo, "dFullName")) gt 0 $>
                        <$getValueForSpecifiedUser(xWF_SendTo, "dFullName")$>      
                    <$else$>
                        <$xWF_SendTo$>            
                        <$endif$>&nbsp;</span></div>
                    </td>

    <!-- ACTION cell -->
                    <td class="<$rowClass$>" style="background-color:transparent;border:1px #000000 solid;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:70px;height:1px;">
                    <div class="xuiListCellDivCenter" nowrap>
                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal">     
                    <$dAction$>&nbsp;</span></div>
                    </td>

    <!-- Approval Type cell -->
                    <td class="<$rowClass$>" style="background-color:transparent;border:1px #000000 solid;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:150px;height:1px;">
                    <div class="xuiListCellDiv" nowrap>
                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal"><$ApprovalType$>&nbsp;</span></div>
                    </td>
    <!-- Comments cell -->

                    <td class="<$rowClass$>" style="background-color:transparent;border:1px #000000 solid;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:250px;height:1px;">
                    <div class="xuiListCellDiv" nowrap>
                    <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal"><$strSubstring(xWorkflowComments,0,100)$>&nbsp;</span> </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>                               
                <$endloop$>

            <tr>
                    <td   colspan="2">
                    [<a href="<$HttpCgiPath$>?IdcService=GET_WORKFLOW_HISTORY_BYNAME&idcToken=<$idcToken$>&dID=<$url(dID)$>&dDocName=<$url(dDocName)$>" style="color:993333;width:50px;font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;font-weight:normal">
                    <$lc("View detailed workflow history")$></a>]                       
                    </td>
            </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: I would remove all the content from your table to make sure it is set up properly - It looks to me as if you have closed off one of your rows without adding the correct amount of columns in (there should be two columns in every row but the row where you have the rowspan column, you only have one column).  Also, your first two columns have a width set to 10% instead of 100%.  You also have an extra semi-colon after width="40%" on the rowspan column.  In the nested table, your colspan should be 5 not 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

position:absolute; set at line 80  caused the table to take a fixed position and hence the issue.

also height="1000" set further set the column's height.Removed it and I'm happy now

Answer (score -1):

Please remove *rowspan="2"* from below td, There should not be rowspan.

**HTML**

```
    <td rowspan="2" width="40%" ;height="1000" style="background:#E6E6D8;min-width:200px">
```